# MailChimp API java integration

Tags: java, email, mailchimp

I try integrate mailChimp API with java code. I refer [MailChimp api tutorial at Codenvy.com](http://docs.codenvy.com/user/tutorials/mailchimp-api-tutorial-3/#create-indexjsp-file-3)
But in function :

```
public String execute() throws Exception{

    ListsMethod listsMethod = new ListsMethod();
    listsMethod.apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us7";
    ListsResult listsResult = mailChimpClient.execute(listsMethod);
    ListInformation data = listsResult.data.get(0);

    CampaignCreateMethod campaignCreateMethod = new CampaignCreateMethod();
    campaignCreateMethod.apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us7";
    campaignCreateMethod.type = CampaignType.plaintext;
    campaignCreateMethod.options = new Options(data.id, "Test Campaign", "abc@xyz.com", "Codenvy", "Codenvy Users");
    campaignCreateMethod.content = new Content("This is a test campaign");
    String campaignId = mailChimpClient.execute(campaignCreateMethod);

    CampaignSendNowMethod campaignSendNowMethod = new CampaignSendNowMethod();
    campaignSendNowMethod.apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us7";
    campaignSendNowMethod.cid = campaignId;
    mailChimpClient.execute(campaignSendNowMethod);

    setMessage("You have successfully created a campaign and sent it to recipients.");
    return "SUCCESS";
}
```

Error at `campaignCreateMethod.options` and `campaignCreateMethod.content`. How can i fix it and how to get all `campaignId` in my account at mailchimp.com ?
[Reference : Wrapped MailChimp API methods](https://github.com/Ecwid/ecwid-mailchimp/wiki/Wrapped-MailChimp-API-methods)

Comment: If that is your real `apikey` from MailChimp, I suggest you edit your post to remove it or obfuscate it so that your lists do not get hijacked

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
 MailChimpClient mailChimpClient = new MailChimpClient();
 ListsMethod listsMethod = new ListsMethod();
 listsMethod.apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
 ListsResult listsResult = mailChimpClient.execute(listsMethod);
 ListInformation data = listsResult.data.get(0);
 System.out.println(data);
 try {
     CampaignCreateMethod campaignCreateMethod = new CampaignCreateMethod();

     campaignCreateMethod.apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
     campaignCreateMethod.type = CampaignType.regular;

     MailChimpObject options = new MailChimpObject();

     campaignCreateMethod.options = new MailChimpObject();
     options.put("list_id", "xxxxxxxxxxc");
     options.put("subject", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
     options.put("from_email", "xxxx@ssss.in");
     options.put("from_name", "xxxxx");
     options.put("authenticate", true);
     options.put("title", "xxxxxxx");
     options.put("tracking", "");
     campaignCreateMethod.options = options;


     String str = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <h1 text-align = center>hi</h1> </head><body text-align=centre><a herf='https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/campaigns/create.php'><i>My First CSS Example</i></a><p>This is a paragraph.</p></body> </html>";

     MailChimpObject content = new MailChimpObject();
     content.put("html", str);
     //content.put("html_HEADER", "xxxxxx");
     //content.put("text", "xxxxxx..... *|UNSUB|*");
     //content.put("url", "https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/campaigncreate.func.php");
     // content.put("type_opts", "regular");
     // content.put("archive", "");
     //content.put("email_type_option", true);

     //content.put("segment_opts", "");
     //content.put("template_id", 1);
     //Set values for MailChimpObject
     campaignCreateMethod.content = content;
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     String responseString = gson.toJson(content);
     System.out.println(responseString);
     String campaignId = mailChimpClient.execute(campaignCreateMethod);

     CampaignSendNowMethod campaignSendNowMethod = new CampaignSendNowMethod();
     campaignSendNowMethod.apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
     campaignSendNowMethod.cid = campaignId;
     mailChimpClient.execute(campaignSendNowMethod);
 } catch (Exception ex) {
     System.out.println(ex);
 }
```